# Pandas error: "IndexError: iloc cannot enlarge its target object"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I want to replace the value of a dataframe cell using pandas. I'm using this line:

```py
submission.iloc[i, coli] = train2.iloc[i2, coli-1]
```

I get the following error line:

```
IndexError: iloc cannot enlarge its target object
```

What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I think this happens because either 'i' or 'coli' is out of bounds in submission. According to the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html?highlight=enlargement#setting-with-enlargement), you can Enlarge the dataframe with loc, meaning it would add the required row and column (in either axis) if you assign a value to a row/column that currently does not exist, but apparently iloc will not do the same.

Answer (score 3):

As its documentation says, pandas dataframes are a data structure that contains labeled axes (rows and columns). `iloc[]` (and `iat[]`) are integer-location based indexers. Enlarging a dataframe means there will have to be a new index label for the enlarged part; however, `iloc` (and `iat`) being integer indexers wouldn't "understand" that.

`loc[]` and `at[]`, being label-based indexers are OK.

```py
df.loc[len(df)] = value
# or
df.at[len(df), 'col'] = value
```

Here the value of `len(df)` becomes the new label.

---

If the job is to add multiple rows to a dataframe, consider using `concat()` instead:

```py
df = pd.concat([df, new_df])
```

If you’re enlarging a dataframe in a loop, see [this benchmark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76132725/19123103) to compare the runtime of these methods.